# Select the latest data with condition

Tags: mongodb

I want to select the latest data of each **type** with **temperature** is not null. So what best way to do that.

Followings is my collection structure.

```
{
 _id: ObjectId,
 type:String,
 temperature: Float,
 timestamp: Long
}
index {timestamp:-1}
```

This is what i'm doing.

```
db.data.aggregate([
{$match:{temperature:{$ne: null}}},
{$sort:{timestamp: -1}},
{$group:{_id: "$type", temperature: {$first: "$temperature"}, timestampe: {$first: "$timestamp"}}}
])
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Now, The total query time is around 3s. And everyday It gets more than 10k docs. I scare one day the collection gonna be big and the query will be slow.